# Zend Guard & Zend Server on Openshift by Redhat

Tags: zend-framework, redhat, guard, openshift

I have created an application on Openshift

Type of application: Zend Server 5.6

but when I run a PHP file encoded with Zend Guard 5.5, it show: "Zend Guard Run-time support missing!"

so How to make it work ?

This is phpinfo: https://f2-htdesignz.rhcloud.com/phpinfo.php

Answer (score 1):

Zend Guard is currently not supported as per details in the following forum thread:  https://www.openshift.com/forums/openshift/how-can-i-enable-zend-optimizer-on-openshift